# How to specify location of create task using schtasks.exe (NOT run-in location)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a task using SCHTASKS.EXE and specify the location is per the following image (Windows 10):

[image]

Is it possible to do this using schtasks? I don't see a parameter for it in Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx). Whenever I create a task, it puts it in the "Task Scheduler Library" folder, not any sub-folder:

[image]

I've only been able to find SO questions regarding trying to specify RUN-IN. This is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I realized you can create a task using the GUI, then export it to XML. Then you can use that file to create the task.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Using: Windows UI

   1. Open *Task Scheduler*
   2. Look for the task browser on the left-hand side of the window. You will see a couple of folders (e.g. `Task Scheduler Library`, `Microsoft`, etc.)
   3. On `Task Scheduler Library`, right click: `New Folder...` (e.g. `Contoso`)
   4. Left-click on `Contoso` to select it.
   5. Right-click on `Contoso` `Create Task`...
2. Using: Command Prompt

   1. Launch command prompt with elevated privileges.
   2. Execute the following: `schtasks.exe /Create /tn "Contoso\MyFirstTask" /SC HOURLY /TR "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"`

      - **Note:** The "Folder Name" (e.g. `Contoso`) is specified as part of the task name (see: `/tn`).
      - **Note:** If the *Task Scheduler* window was open prior to executing the command from the command line... you may have to refresh the task browser to see the new `Contoso` folder.

These instructions assume that you have the appropriate Windows permissions to create a new task.